# Twitter API returning The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: java, twitter

The API https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json is working if I pass only (status) but as soon as I add parameters it gives me error (401).

```
string postBody = "status=test&display_coordinates=false";
byte[] bodyBytes = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(postBody);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your signing code is also including these new params, I would suspect you are not sorting the params.

Look at https://github.com/twitter/joauth/blob/master/src/main/java/com/twitter/joauth/Normalizer.java#L95

But generally you should provide more context and example code.